# Temporarily mount SMD 2x5 header for programming

Tags: soldering, surface-mount, programming, header, glue

I can't mount the 2x5 header permanently on the PCB, so need a way to temporarily mount it to the solder pad the PCB already has for this 2x5 header. Soldering it would create a mess and is not a quick way to mount it. Any suggestions on what could be used to hold the header to the pads, use it for programming, and then take it off in a clean way once done using it. I saw some similar threads but they mostly talk about keeping the component in place to assist soldering, I am looking for an alternative to soldering to temporarily mount an SMD header component.

Comment: If you want reliable connections involving the header you have to solder it. If you don’t need to involve the header maybe you could use pogo pins and a fixture.

Comment: Pogo pins and a fixture is the standard way. If you need the board to be movable, you could 3d print a "fixture" that latches onto the board somehow.

Comment: Thanks, I have thought about a fixture with bed of nails but that sounded like an overkill. But I will continue considering it if no other simpler clean hack.

Comment: there are some pre-made pogo-pins cables for debugging/flashing that are available on the market if you're willing to pay 40€+

Comment: Found some spring loaded pogo pins but I will have to work on a custom cable assembly.

Comment: Have someone competent solder and desolder it? It's trivial to desolder a SMD header if you are allowed to cut it first. So it's either a 0.1€ SMT header or those 40€ something pogo pins. I believe it's a so-called no-brainer?

Comment: However, I suspect that the _actual_ solution to your _actual_ problem is that you should be buying pre-programmed MCUs instead of empty ones. Yeah?

Comment: @Lundin this is more of a reprogramming than fresh  programming.

Comment: Well it's all about volumes then. If it is low volumes then solder/desolder. It its hundreds, go for pogo pins. Either way, if this is products that have been out in the field or collecting dust in some warehouse, you probably need to clean the pads with isopropyl first.